# Get latest row for threads in QA table

Tags: mysql, sql

This a simplified version of my SQL table for questions and answers, post_id is the primary key.

```
 post_id | ref_post_id | title  | date (unix timestamp)
   1     |     0       | Title1 |  10 
   2     |     1       |        |  20 
   3     |     0       | Title2 |  30
```

When ref_post_id is 0, that means it's a question. When it is not 0 it's an answer where the number corresponds to the question's post_id. That means that the second row is an answer to the first row in my example above.

What I want to do is to get only the last row of every question. If the question does not have any answers I want the question row, but if it has answers I want the last answer but I want to join in the title that belongs to the question row.

I've googled and tried myself for a while now. Hopefully you understand my problem!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would reccommend to split your table in two different tables, one for the questions and one for the answer.

However, the query you need could be written as this:

```
SELECT posts.*
FROM
  posts INNER JOIN
    (SELECT IF(ref_post_id=0,post_id,ref_post_id) as id, Max(Date) as maxdate
     FROM posts
     GROUP BY id) p
  ON
    (p.maxdate = posts.date) AND
    (p.id =IF(posts.ref_post_id=0,posts.post_id,posts.ref_post_id))
```

To select max date for every question/answer you have to group by `ref_post_id`, except the case in which `ref_post_id = 0` where you have to group by `post_id`, hence the IF.

When you join the posts table with itself, using the subquery, you have to use the same trick.

**EDIT:** if you need to mark a question as deleted, then you have to remove all deleted questions and answers from the select above, and you have to use one more subquery to select only undeleted questions:

```
SELECT posts.*
FROM
  posts INNER JOIN
    (SELECT IF(ref_post_id=0,post_id,ref_post_id) as id, Max(Date) as maxdate
     FROM posts
     WHERE EXISTS (SELECT null 
                   FROM posts posts_sub
                   WHERE
                     posts_sub.post_id =
                     IF(posts.ref_post_id=0,posts.post_id,posts.ref_post_id)
                   AND posts_sub.deleted =0)
     GROUP BY id) p
  ON
    (p.maxdate = posts.date) AND
    (p.id =IF(posts.ref_post_id=0,posts.post_id,posts.ref_post_id))
```

Comment: How would I change the SQL query to also say WHERE NOT deleted = 1 so that it does not retrieve posts that are deleted?

Comment: you have to add the condition in your subquery `SELECT .. FROM POSTS WHERE NOT deleted=1 GROUP BY...` and i think it's better to add the same condition on the main query

Comment: As it turns out, it still doesn't work after I did what you said. The query still returns answers where the main question post is deleted. Hope you understand.

Comment: so i guess that there's a field `deleted` in your table, questions can be marked as deleted while answers are not... if so, you have to add a subquery... i'll edit my answer

Comment: Hopefully I'm done bothering you! :) Thanks a lot, it works great!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to split your table in two, one for the questions and one for the answers.

A rough sketch of how this would look:

```
questions
post_id  |  title  |  date

answers
answer_id  |  post_id  |  answer  |  date
```

That way you can request the last answer of the requested question in the following way:

```
SELECT * FROM answers WHERE post_id = THE_REQUESTED_POST_ID ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

EDIT:

Crap sorry, I said the wrong table, the table to select from should be answers.

Comment: using `LIMIT 1` doesn't give you the result what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.replyID
FROM    tableName a
        LEFT JOIN tableName c
            ON a.ref_post_ID = c.post_id
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT ref_post_ID replyID, MAX(DATE) as maxDATE
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY replyID
        ) latestAnswer
            ON  c.ref_post_ID = latestAnswer.replyID AND
                c.date = latestAnswer.maxDATE
```

I highly recommend, that you make a separate table for this, one is for `Question` and second for `Answers` and which a column from `Answers` table is a foreign from `Question` table.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
SELECT t.*, lastAnswer.title  FROM tableName t LEFT JION 
(SELECT t1.*
    FROM tableName t1 LEFT JOIN tableName t2
     ON (t1.ref_post_id = t2.ref_post_id AND t1.date < t2.date)
    WHERE t2.ref_post_id IS NULL AND t1.ref_post_id > 0
) lastAnswer
ON t.post_id = lastAnswer.ref_post_id
WHERE t.ref_post_id = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I already posted a solution, but assuming `post_id` is always ordered, i like this one more since it's more simple:

```
select
  posts.*, posts_1.title
from
  posts left join posts posts_1
  on posts.ref_post_id = posts_1.post_id
where posts.post_id IN (select max(post_id) from posts
group by IF(posts.ref_post_id=0,posts.post_id,posts.ref_post_id))
```

(i'm using the same trick of grouping by `ref_post_id` or by `post_id`).

**EDIT:** if you need to select only undeleted posts, this is what you need:

```
select
  posts.*,
  posts_1.title
from
  posts left join posts posts_1
  on posts.ref_post_id = posts_1.post_id
where
  posts.post_id IN (select max(post_id) from posts
                    where exists (select * 
                      from posts posts_sub
                      where
                        posts_sub.post_id =
                        if(posts.ref_post_id=0,posts.post_id,posts.ref_post_id)
                        and posts_sub.deleted =0)
group by
  IF(posts.ref_post_id=0,posts.post_id,posts.ref_post_id))
```